# Usage of Group By and Order By in Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

The table from which I have tried to read

[image: table]

Here I am trying to read the rows which has the latest TransactionDate and grouped by StackHistoryID.

So I thought of using "order by TransactionDate desc" first then the latest row will be top and if I use group by after that it will give what i have wanted. But I figured that, We can not use groupby after using orderby. So I struck here, Is there any way to get what I have wanted using a single query.

UPDATE:

```
select ID, Max(TransactionDate) from Stacks group by StackHistoryID
```

[image]

But the ID for the first row in this output should be 9.

Comment: The ID is not the "ID" it is the StackHistoryID, and it is what you have grouped. The output is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> [**<kbd>See SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2185/1)

**use MAX()**

```
select StackHistoryID, Max(TransactionDate)
from Stacks
group by StackHistoryID;
```

**And simple query with ID, use MAX; (if the ID is incremental, i.e. higher id can not have lower date):**

```
select Max(ID),StackHistoryID, Max(TransactionDate)
from Stacks
group by StackHistoryID;
```

**And if your ID is not incremental together with date, i.e. you could have a higher ID with lower date... Then you could do something like:**

```
select alls.ID, s.StackHistoryID, s.TransactionDate
from
(
  select StackHistoryID as StackHistoryID, 
         Max(TransactionDate) as TransactionDate
  from stacks
  group by StackHistoryID desc 
) s, Stacks alls
where
  alls.StackHistoryID = s.StackHistoryID
  and
  alls.TransactionDate = s.TransactionDate
order by StackHistoryID
;
```

> [**<kbd>See SQLFiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2185/1)

Comment: I'd prefer to explicitly use `JOIN` but I agree on all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data for `stackhistoryid` with `transactiondate` sorted. then go for.

```
select * from stacks order by StackHistoryID, TransactionDate desc;
```

If you need only latest date go for result specified by `@MrSimpleMind`